# rpcallowip=192.168.0.* ?? invalid configuration

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, bitcoin.conf

I recently downloaded bitcoin from github and changed the settings to allow for rpc.

This is how I have it:

```
rpcallowip=192.168.0.*
```

This does not work anymore.

However when running bitcoind, it complains that:

```
Error: Invalid -rpcallowip subnet specification: 192.168.0.*.
Valid are a single IP, a network/netmask or a network CIDR.
```

I'm not that familiar with networking.

Can someone tell me what a valid network/netmask or network/CIDR is for all addresses that could be in 192.168.0.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to use `192.168.0.0/24`. That's CIDR notation for 192.168.0.*.